# Unknown symbols displayed in czech words in javascript application

Tags: javascript, encoding

I have an unknown symbols displayed in my javascript application for try catch construction using czech language even when I use coding windows-1250. These symbols is displayed like question marks in diamond.

html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250"/>
<title>Konstrukce Try/Catch</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="number.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="formular" id="formular" action="#">
<div id="cisloDiv">Zadejte číslo v rozsahu 1 až 100: <input id="cislo" name="cislo"> <span id="informace"> </span></div>
<div><input id="odeslatFormular" type="submit"></div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">

function inicializuj() {
    document.forms[0].onsubmit = function() { return zkontrolujFormular(this) };
}
window.onload = inicializuj;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

javascript

```
function zkontrolujFormular() {
    try {
        var cislo = document.forms[0]["cislo"];
        if (isNaN(cislo.value)) {
            var chyba = new Array("Nejedná se o číslo",cislo);
            throw chyba;
        }
        else if (cislo.value > 100) {
            var chyba = new Array("Zadané číslo je větší jak 100",cislo);
            throw chyba;
        }
        else if (cislo.value < 1) {
            var chyba = new Array("Zadané číslo je menší jak 1",cislo);
            throw chyba;
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch(objektVyjimky) {
        var informace = document.getElementById("informace");
        var textChyby = document.createTextNode(objektVyjimky[0]);
        var novySpan = document.createElement("span");
        novySpan.appendChild(textChyby);
        novySpan.style.color = "#FF0000";
        novySpan.style.fontWeight = "bold";
        novySpan.setAttribute("id","informace");
        var rodic = informace.parentNode;
        rodic.replaceChild(novySpan,informace);
        objektVyjimky[1].style.background = "#FF0000";
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try <script type="text/javascript" charset="windows-1250"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using UTF-8 encoding?

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

or shorter:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Nowadays using encoding other that UTF-8 is rather rare. You may need it in special circumstances, but whenever you can try to use UTF.

Comment: It's impossible. UTF-8 contains nearly every sign you could think of.
Your problem must be elsewhere. What is your file encoding, and are you just opening it from drive or via some server (like Apache)?

Answer (score 0):

Now I have the solution, something was bad in my code because in solution (it is from learning material) it works.